# add a class to element with specific data-filter attribute?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm in need of a bit of a jQuery hack for this WordPress project. It's generating links with data-filters but no unique IDs or anything.

```
<a data-filter=".term73" href="#">
```

And I'd like to manually tell .term73 to have class "active" when the page loads. I've used the addClass() function before, but can't seem to find how to do that to an element by data-filter (as opposed to ID). Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('a[data-filter=".term73"]').addClass('active');
```

or even

```
$('a[data-filter=".term73"][href="#"]').addClass('active');
```

just to point out how you can target attributes.

While I'm at it, an alternative which might be good to know, but overkill for this scenario:

```
$('a[href="#"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('filter') === '.term73';
}).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure that works but for some reason WP isn't playing nice. I'm getting "$ isn't a function" even though I see jQuery loading in the header...

Comment: Try with jQuery('a[data-filter ... as they may not be allowing the $ as an alias.

Comment: Perfect! Lol... now the problem is that it is styling it like it should, class wise, but it's not activating the script that actually kicks it over to filter by that selection. Oi vey.